# Open source analogs of FFMpeg

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing

Are there any strong similar libraries like FFMpeg command line library?
This library must support video file metadata grabbing in order to read necessary video metadata.

Thank you.

Comment: what is wrong with FFMpeg? It is also open source.

Answer (score 0):

Vlc (http://www.videolan.org/vlc) and mencoder (http://www.mplayerhq.hu ) are other two popular video encoding decoding tools and these are also open source..

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide example of how get video dimension with the help of Vlc or Mencoder?